# Getting file extension in Django template

Tags: python, django

I have model like this:

```
class File(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files')
```

I get all File objects in my view and according to the type of file, I would like to print appropriate a class:

```
<a class="pdf">link</a>
```

or

```
<a class="word">link</a>
```

or

```
<a class="other">link<a/>
```

in my template.

How can I get file extension in Django template?

I would like to do somethink like this:

```
{% for file in files %}
    {% if file.get_extension == 'pdf' %}
           <a class="pdf">link</a>
    {% elif file.get_extension = '.doc' %}
           <a class="word">link</a>
    {% else %}
           <a class="other">link<a/>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Of course, 'file.get_extension' doesn't exist...

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You're missing a `.get_extension` on your model? That's easy, just add it :-) You can have all sorts of methods on a model. So something like this:

```
class File(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files')

    def extension(self):
        name, extension = os.path.splitext(self.file.name)
        return extension
```

(The name `.extension()` is more pythonic than `.get_extension()`, btw).

You can go even further. Isn't that if/else structure a bit tedious in your template? It is less of a hassle in Python code:

```
class File(models.Model):
    ...
    def css_class(self):
        name, extension = os.path.splitext(self.file.name)
        if extension == 'pdf':
            return 'pdf'
        if extension == 'doc':
            return 'word'
        return 'other'
```

The template is simpler this way:

```
{% for file in files %}
  <a class="{{ file.css_class }}">link</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if there is a nifty built in django function to do this, but you can get the extension from your filefield

`fileName, fileExtension = os.path.splitext(file.name)`

If you're set on doing this in your template you can create a custom tag which wraps this

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/