# Check file extension in Django FileField

Tags: python, django

I need to run a different code depending on the extension of the file.

This is a simplified version of the model:

```
class SuplierList(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='fornecedores/')
```

This is the part of the view that I have the problem:

```
table = request.GET.get("table")
ft = FornecedorTabela.objects.filter(id=table)[0]
file = ft.file
if re.match('.pdf$', ft.file.name):
```

I don't know how I should write this last condition above. With this version above, I get the error: The 'python' engine cannot iterate through this file buffer.

How show I write this condition?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting file extension in Django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455052/getting-file-extension-in-django-template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.endswith`

**Ex:**

```
table = request.GET.get("table")
ft = FornecedorTabela.objects.filter(id=table)[0]
file = ft.file
if ft.file.name.endswith('.pdf'):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just limit the file browser popup window to the expected extension.

```py
class SupplierForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = SuplierList
        fields = ['file',]
        widgets = {
            "file": forms.FileInput(attrs={
                'accept': ".pdf"}
            ),
        }
```